# CodeCademy Intro to Objects II Trouble finding error

Tags: javascript

For this assignment the object 'languages' was created for you. the assignment is to use a 'for-in' loop to write three different ways to say 'hello.' I want to use an 'if' statement to check that the property is a 'string' and if so, print that version of 'hello' to the console. I am stuck and getting an error stating a "there was a problem with your syntax."

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages
for (var x in obj) {
    var typeCheck = languages.x;
    if {
        (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
            console.log(typeCheck;)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looping with an undefined variable `obj`. Use the defined one `languages` instead.

```
for (var x in languages) {
    var typeCheck = x;
    if {
        (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
            console.log(typeCheck;)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I noticed there was a lot errors in your code.

**Your `if statement`**

Which is not how to use it, currently it is :

```
if {
      (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
        console.log(typeCheck;)
      }
}
```

**Change that to :**

```
if (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
     console.log(typeCheck);
}
```

Then your ending semi colon on the `console.log()`, it should be after the ending `)`.

**So from :**

```
console.log(typeCheck;)
```

**To :**

```
console.log(typeCheck);
```

**Putting them together :**

```
for (var x in languages) {
    var typeCheck = x;
    if (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
            console.log(typeCheck);
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't syntactically valid

Comment: @jdphenix yeah, I was updating the code when I noticed that.

Comment: Yes I see that, Good deal :D

Comment: thank you guys for the help. the last 'putting them together' section from robin is almost in just needs to fix the typeCheck variable. so this is what worked:   for (var x in languages) {
    var typeCheck = languages[x];
    if (typeof typeCheck === "string") {
            console.log(typeCheck);
    }

}

Answer (score 2):

Using the code suggested by Robin, I've modified it to be the following final solution.

```
for (var x in languages) { 
    var typeCheck = languages[x]; 
    if (typeof typeCheck === "string") { 
        console.log(typeCheck); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems here:

- `for (var x in obj) {` - This loops on some object `obj` which is undefined in this context. You need to loop over `languages`.
- [`if {`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) - if statements have the form form of `if (condition)`, not what you have there.

Here is a correctly version that [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of `languages` and performs the type check.

```js
    var languages = {
      english: "Hello!",
      french: "Bonjour!",
      notALanguage: 4,
      spanish: "Hola!"
    };

    Object.keys(languages).forEach(function(key) {
      if (typeof languages[key] === "string") {
        console.log(languages[key]);
      }
    });
```

Comment: it is specifically looking for us to use a 'for-in' loop in this instance

Comment: It's specifically looking for you to use a poor practice unless you guard it with `hasOwnProperty()` - I would just use `Object.keys().forEach()` here